# confused about base64 encoding of BLOBs when using dropwizard

Tags: json, blob, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard app running against postgres and a table. I define the BLOB column in the entity class as byte[]:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "my.documents.model.Document.findAll",
                query = "SELECT d FROM Document d"
        )
})
public class Document {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "documentName", nullable = false)
    private String documentName;

    @Column(name = "documentData")
    private byte[] documentData;    
    ...
 }
```

When I test the POST API using curl or postman I encode the BLOB data string ("my mlob data") using base64 first. Note that it won't let me submit without encoding:

```
{"documentName":"Invoice1","documentData":"bXkgYmxvYiBkYXRhCg=="}
```

In the API I would expect to have to decode the bytes manually, but no, it appears to already have been decoded. The code snippet below prints "my blob data".

```
@Path("/documents")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DocumentsResource {

    @POST
    @UnitOfWork
    public Document createDocument(Document document) {
        byte[] data = document.getDocumentData();
         System.out.println("new String(data));
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

However, when I test the API using a java server side client, and encode with Base64, it will still come as encoded on the API end:

```
Client client;
Document document;
String s = new String("my blob data");
document.setdocumentData(Base64.encode(s.getBytes());

client.target(myurl).request()
  .post(Entity.entity(document, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
```

And when I send plain, unencoded string (or binary) it comes out correct on the receiving API end.

I don't understand:

- Why the data gets magically decoded when I invoke the API through curl or postman
- Why the API works without encoding when invoking it through from the java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson serializes and deserializes `byte[]` fields using base64 encoder [automatically](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/10/entry_330.html).

Your mistake is base64 encoding it manually before Jackson does it, which means it's base64 encoded twice on JSON.

You should change

```
document.setdocumentData(Base64.encode(s.getBytes()));
```

to

```
document.setdocumentData(s.getBytes());
```